# 2 "P4" power connectors *AND* an 8 pin EPS connector -- all necessary?

Tags: atx

I recently bought an Arima SW350 motherboard.

It supports 16 ddr simms as well as 2 opteron 2xx CPUs, so I imagine it may have pretty heavy power requirements...

It has a [24 pin ATX power connector](http://www.playtool.com/pages/psuconnectors/connectors.html#atxmain24), 2 [4 pin "P4" power connectors](http://www.playtool.com/pages/psuconnectors/connectors.html#eps4plus4), *and* [an 8 pin EPS power connector](http://www.playtool.com/pages/psuconnectors/connectors.html#eps8).

My supermicro power supply has a 24 pin ATX connector and the EPS connector, and *one* P4 connector.

Can I safely run this thing with only one P4 connector plugged in?  Can I safely get a ["hard disk to P4" adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BX4J9O) and use that to power the other P4 connector on the motherboard?  Do I just need a new power supply?

The board's documentation is pretty thin on the topic.

Comment: Side note - I think they're DIMMs and not SIMMs

Comment: I should have used the technical term "memory thingies"

Comment: Of course they’re DIMMs; SIMMs were not DDR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read it,the two side power connectors are power out